# Proof about the hierarchy of sets: show that $V_{\alpha + 1} = \mathcal P(V_{\alpha})$

Tags: set-theory

Define

$$V_0 = \varnothing,$$

$$V_1 = V_0 \cup \mathcal P(V_0),$$

$$V_2 = V_1 \cup \mathcal P(V_1),$$

and so on. In general,

$$V_{\alpha + 1} = V_{\alpha} \cup \mathcal P(V_{\alpha}),$$

and, if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, $$V_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} V_\beta. $$

Show that

$$V_{\alpha + 1} = \mathcal P(V_{\alpha}), \quad \forall \alpha \lt \omega.$$

My try:

\begin{align}
V_{\alpha + 1} = V_{\alpha} \cup \mathcal P(V_{\alpha}) = \mathcal P(V_{\alpha}) & \Leftrightarrow V_{\alpha} \subseteq \mathcal P(V_{\alpha}) \\
 & \Leftrightarrow \forall v_{\alpha} \in V_{\alpha} (v_{\alpha} \in \mathcal P(V_{\alpha})) \\
 & \Leftrightarrow \forall v_{\alpha} \in V_{\alpha} (v_{\alpha} \subseteq V_{\alpha}). \\
\end{align}

I observed that

$$V_{\alpha} = V_{\alpha - 1} \cup \mathcal P(V_{\alpha - 1}).$$

Thus,

$$\forall v_{\alpha} \in V_{\alpha} ((v_{\alpha} \in V_{\alpha - 1}) \lor (v_{\alpha} \subseteq V_{\alpha - 1})).$$

$$(v_{\alpha} \subseteq V_{\alpha - 1}) \land (V_{\alpha - 1} \subseteq V_{\alpha}) \Rightarrow v_{\alpha} \subseteq V_{\alpha}.$$

Now it remains to prove that if $v_{\alpha} \in V_{\alpha - 1}$, then $v_{\alpha} \subseteq V_{\alpha}$. How do I proceed? And I feel I am in the wrong direction...

Comment: It is generally the case that if you want to prove something for ordinals, it's a good idea to use induction. Here this is also the case. If you had an induction assumption on $V_\alpha$, it would have simplified things.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, yes. But induction doesn't lead to numbers greater than $\omega$ and I don't really know how to use transfinite induction...

Comment: Show that $$V_{\alpha + 1} = \mathcal P(V_{\alpha}), \quad \forall \alpha \lt \omega.$$ You weren't asked to deal with the transfinite case.

Comment: Yes, but as you said, this still holds true for the transfinite case, so... well, a bit beyond this question. Anyway, does my attempt lead to a proof?

Comment: Again, you would need to use some sort of induction. I don't see any other way. If you had an induction hypothesis for $V_\alpha$, it would solve your problem.

Comment: Please excuse my naive question, but isn't $V_{\alpha +1}
= {\cal P}(V_\alpha)$ just the definition of $V_{\alpha+1}$ when $\alpha$ is not a limit ordinal?

Comment: @Robert: Yes. But here the definition was slightly different, and the question was to prove the equivalence to the usual definition.

Comment: @RobertSingleton The definition here is perhaps a more natural naive definition than the usual one, since we want our hierarchy to be increasing and it might not be obvious at the outset that $V_\alpha \subseteq  V_{\alpha+1}$ under the $V_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal P(V_\alpha)$ definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier than that:

If $X$ is a transitive set, then $X\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$. Simply show that for every $\alpha$, $V_\alpha$ is transitive. And for that, it's easy to prove that:

1. If $X$ is transitive, then $\mathcal P(X)$ is transitive.
2. If $\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a collection of transitive sets, then $\bigcup\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ is transitive.

Comment: That's, by the way, an excellent example of "generalize something to make it easier".

Comment: Thanks! Yet another question, for what values of $\alpha$ does $V_{\alpha + 1} = \mathcal P(V_{\alpha})$ hold?

Comment: All of them. That's essentially what I'm saying.

Comment: Oh, I see. And just curious, does my attempt eventually lead to a proof?